# HDMI Conntection between PC and TV(problm)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

So, i bought a TV(Philips 40pus6809) and 2 new HDMI cables a month ago. At first i used the cables with my laptop and they did not have any problems-everything worked perfectly. 1 day ago i wanted to connect it to my PC, but it did not work. 
When the TV is turned off, the computer finds the TV. 
But when i turn on the TV, it dissapears from the computer.

Do you have any solutions? (The question might be dumb but i dont know much about HDMI problems)[sorry for the bulgarian language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGuxB.png)

Comment: Do you have the proper input selected on the TV menu?

Comment: I do not have inputs button..

Comment: its buried in the onscreen menu then, read your owners manual on how to select inputs.

Comment: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/953452/Philips-40puk6809.html?page=44#manual

Comment: I did everything, but still says no signal...
http://prnt.sc/c62eq4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because the problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my firmware and everything works fine now.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: When you can you can accept your own answer and gain rep for yourself and an answer for the site. thanks